# use "Google Wallet for Digital Goods API " in TAIWAN?

Tags: billing, android-pay

Now I've to sign up for Google Wallet for Digital Goods (sandbox) , 
I want to set up a online billing for customer by using the Google wallet.

But when I entry this page
https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/inapp/merchant/signup.html

I can't find the "Taiwan" at "Country/Region" ,
Does it means that Taiwan can't use this service ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time Google Wallet for Digital Goods is not available for Taiwan merchants. The link below has a list of eligible countries:

https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/faq#faq-gen-02

Australia

Austria

Belgium

Canada

Denmark

Finland

France

Germany

Ireland

Italy

Japan

The Netherlands

Norway

Portugal

Spain

Sweden

United Kingdom

United States